# Copiar columna de un Dataframe a otro en Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframes, los cuales tienen una columna llamada codigo_dx. En el primer dataframe he creado una columna llamada codigo_id con un código de tipo unsigned 32 que está relacionada con los valores de codigo_dx para hacer las consultas posteriores más sencillas. En el segundo dataframe quiero poner la misma columna de codigo_id para que me salgan los mismos valores de codigo_id respecto al codigo_dx. Por ejemplo en el primer dataframe tengo:

| codigo_dx | codigo_id |
| --- | --- |
| R13 | 1 |
| M25 | 2 |
| D10 | 3 |

En el segundo dataframe tengo la columna codigo_dx con códigos iguales a los del primer dataframe y quiero crear la columna codigo_id pero que cuando salga el codigo_dx R13, el codigo_id también sea 1 y no otro número.

El código que yo había intentado es el siguiente:

```
df2.codigo_dx = df1.codigo_dx.astype("category") 
df2["codigo_id"] = df2.codigo_dx.cat.codes + 1
```

Así creaba la columna codigo_id en el df2, pero no me coinciden los códigos con los del primer dataframe. Entonces he intentado realizar un merge:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='codigo_dx')
```

Pero con esto solo consigo que se me unan todas las filas de los dos dataframes y yo quiero las mismas filas que df2 ya tenía en su origen, pero con un codigo_id que sea el mismo respecto a sus codigos_dx que en el df1.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es hacer un left join de df2 y df1 tienes o bien que cambiae el orden de los dataframes en el join, o utilizar `how='right'`

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='codigo_dx')
```

o

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='codigo_dx', how='right')
```